# At what point are all Viewgroup children created and ready to set some initial properties?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

I am working on a custom ViewGroup that extends LinearLayout but only accepts children of a particular subclass. At the first possible moment I have the opportunity, I want to set some properties on the children (things like their index etc). In Flex there is a method called createChildren() where all children are created and then an event called creationComplete is fired (the children are created but not measured/laid out yet). Whats the equivalent in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for adding properties to the view before it is drawn? If not than you can use `myViewGroup.setTag(myObjectTag)` to attach an object to the view (perhaps Integer since you want to use it to index) and `myViewGroup.getTag()` to return the view's object "tag".